# Ruby compare if the elements of array are one of these characters

Tags: ruby, object, compare

```
g = [["xx", "A"],­ ["xx", "B"]]­
g.any?{­|x,y| y.eq­l? ("A"|­|"B"||"C"­)}
```

I want to evaluate if the 2nd element in the sub-array is one of "A"or"B"or"C". In the above case it should return `true`. And return `false`, example, `if g=[["xx","K"]["xx","B"]`.

Comment: You'd better to format your code, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with a combination of both the above answers

```
1.9.3p194 :177 > g =[["xx", "A"],["xx", "B"]]
 => [["xx", "A"], ["xx", "B"]] 
1.9.3p194 :178 > g.all?  {|i,v| "ABC".include?v}
 => true  #correctly return true
1.9.3p194 :179 > g =[["xx", "A"],["xx", "Ba"]]
 => [["xx", "A"], ["xx", "Ba"]] 
1.9.3p194 :180 > g.all?  {|i,v| "ABC".include?v}
 => false #correctly return false
```

EDIT After benchmarks Inspired by @victor's answer

```
array= ['A','B','C']
g.all? { |x,y| arr.include?y
```

and

```
h = {"A" => true, "B" => true, "C" => true}
g.all? { |x,y| h.has_key?(y)
```

are winners.

Benchmark's Inspired by @victor answer

```
require 'benchmark'

many = 500000

g = [["x", "A"], ["xx", "B"]]
h = {"A" => true, "B" => true, "C" => true}
arr = ['A','B','C']

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report("regexp1\t") {many.times { g.all? { |x,y| y =~ /^(A|B|C)$/} } }
  b.report("regexp2\t") { many.times { g.all? { |x,y| y =~ /^[ABC]$/ } } }
  b.report("hash\t") { many.times { g.all? { |x,y| h.has_key?(y) } } }
  b.report("str include\t") { many.times { g.all? { |x,y| "ABC".include?y } } }
  b.report("array include\t") { many.times { g.all? { |x,y| arr.include?y } } }
end

#Output 
       user     system      total        real
regexp1           0.640000   0.000000   0.640000 (  0.635750)
regexp2           0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.586788)
hash              0.370000   0.000000   0.370000 (  0.364140)
str include       0.430000   0.010000   0.440000 (  0.439753)
array include     0.380000   0.010000   0.390000 (  0.381149)
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you PriteshJ for all the details.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
g.all? { |x,y| y =~ /^(A|B|C)$/ }
```

**Edit**: after @PriteshJ's observation

Comment: can also use /^[ABC]$/ instead of /^(A|B|C)$/

Answer (score 1):

I think `("A" || "B" || "C")` alway gives you `"A"`.

```
  g.each{|x, y| puts "ABC".include? y}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like good old hash is faster than regexp:

```
require 'benchmark'

many = 500000

g = [["x", "A"], ["xx", "B"]]
h = {"A" => true, "B" => true, "C" => true}
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report("regexp") { many.times { g.all? { |x,y| y =~ /^(A|B|C)$/ } } }
  b.report("hash") { many.times { g.all? { |x,y| h.has_key?(y) } } }
end

# regexp  1.690000   0.000000   1.690000 (  1.694377)
# hash  1.040000   0.000000   1.040000 (  1.040016)
```

Comment: very cool @Victor Moroz check my updated ans I found something more interesting :)